# Galaxy Mk2, plastic thingy next to windshield

Tags: ford, windshield, galaxy

I have 2014 Ford Galaxy Mk2. The plastic strip (don't know the proper name for it in English) next to the windshield keeps coming off. The tabs that are supposed to hold it in place may be slightly broken.

Is this thing purely decorative, or does it have some function? I was thinking of permanently gluing it in place with epoxy. Is this a bad idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly decorative, but probably also reduces wind noise. These strips usually cover up the weld seams where the roof meets the body. If you don't feel as though you care too much about it (ie: will never replace the strips), glueing it down with epoxy wouldn't be a bad thing. You won't hurt anything structurally by doing so, though if you're not careful, you could make it look very ugly. You'd just have to be careful with the epoxy and clean up any excess which might squish out before it sets up. You'll also want to ensure it is firmly put in place for a period of time while the epoxy sets up. IOW: give it a chance to completely bond and adhere.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found this thread http://fordgalaxy.org.uk/ford/topic/25400-windscreen-edge-trim-came-off-how-to-repair/?tab=comments, which seems to be talking about the same thing. The OEM replacement part is quite expensive. The thread recommends polyurethane for fixing it into place, so maybe I'll use that instead of epoxy.

Comment: Then consider when you need the screen replaced.

Comment: Perhaps silicone calk. It would be removeable in case you need to replace the windscreen...